# Does jQuery's $.get function create unnecessary HTTP Requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, get

in order to increase my site's loading times and as a nice addition, I decided to implement AJAX page loading using the jQuery function **$.get.**

I was pleased to see that, just as I had expected, the content that was the same across two sites remained static while only the different part was loaded.

However, now I am wondering: When $.get fetches a new page that also includes scripts and stylesheets, but when those are the same to the previous page, does the browser still send a new HTTP Request for those elements? If it did, that would sort of ruin the purpose of the feature.

Thanks!

Comment: The browser should load identical resources from the disk or memory cache and not over the network as long as cache settings in browser or page or resource don't prohibit that.  They will be parsed again and reloaded though, just not retrieved over the network.

Comment: Make sure that you don't break bookmarking, linking, etc by making use of [the history api](http://caniuse.com/#search=history) and falling back to server side generation of pages.

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly does the history API do?

Comment: Follow the link, read the things marked as Resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching works in the same way for resources referenced by adding elements to an existing page as it does for those referenced by loading a new page with those elements in it. So it won't make any difference.

That said, if you are loading the *whole* page via Ajax (as your mention of scripts and stylesheets suggests you are), then you aren't going to save yourself any time, since you aren't reducing the amount of data being transfered. That is only going to make a difference if you are loading (relatively) small *parts* of a page.

Comment: But if the user does not have the cache yet? Will it then make a difference? Also, can you give me a good reason why a lot of the big sites are now featuring AJAX page loading?

Comment: If the user does not have the cache, then they wouldn't be **re**loading the content (either that or the content would be reloaded no matter how you get them to the new "page").

Answer (score 0):

Inserting HTML will drop script and link tags. I.e. if your AJAX response is

```
<div>test</div>
<script src="...."></script>
```

only `div` will be inserted.

If you wanna be sure, open Fiddler or Firebug and see what happens.